# How to add a required value for optional parameter when using argparse in Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

So I am trying to implement argparse in my Python code.
I want to have lets say 4 possible arguments that could be passed. But, if I choose the fourth then I would need an additional argument, but I can't implement this.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Testing arguments')
parser.add_argument("--a", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--b", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--c", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--d", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Example:

```
python3 mycode.py --a #no further argument needed  
python3 mycode.py --d further_argument # further argument needed
```

I have read some of the posts on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't really find the thing I need.

Comment: Can you use '--d' as the default 'store' Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an optional argument take a value you have to add it like this:

```
parser.add_argument("--d", nargs=1)
```

it means that if `--d` is specified than it needs one (and only one) value. [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) keyword can also have `*`, `?`, `+` for different type of optional values.
Default value for `--d` when not specified will be `None` but this can be changed with `default=False`.

```
# --a doesn't need a value
>>> parser.parse_args('--a'.split())
Namespace(a=True, b=False, c=False, d=None)

# --d does need a value
>>> parser.parse_args('--d'.split())
usage: [-h] [--a] [--b] [--c] [--d D]
: error: argument --d: expected 1 argument

>>> parser.parse_args('--d VALUE'.split())
Namespace(a=False, b=False, c=False, d=['VALUE'])
```

When specified, `--d` value will always be type of `list` with a single string (for `nargs=1`).

Also because you are using `--` with single letter arguments it makes them long  optional arguments that cannot be stacked together. If you change it to `-` you can run your program like this:

```
>>> parser.parse_args('-abcd VALUE'.split())
Namespace(a=True, b=True, c=True, d=['VALUE'])
```

Comment: full answer, well written. I think, I will improve my code with your suggestions. I have already solved my problem by just removing the "action=..." part, but again, your answer will be selected as the answer, since you provided additional information.